# How to use utm_source with Github analytics

Tags: analytics, referrer, github

I have a resource hosted in a public Github repository. I am using Github Analytics to estimate the traffic coming to the resource. Since Github also shows referring sites on the traffic page, I'd like to understand how I can modify the Github URL to the resource, that I use on my server, so that I see my server in the list of referrers. I tried appending `?utm_source=servername` but that doesn't seem to work with Github.

**Edit:** As per the comments below, I am trying to find the equivalent of `utm_source` for Github, if any.

Comment: UTM stands for Urchin Tracking Module.  Google bought Urchin and renamed it Google Analytics.   So `utm_source` is purely a Google Analytics thing, and I wouldn't expect it to work in any other analytics package.  I'm sure you want to know if there is an equivalent from Github Analytics, but I've never used it.